# Import geometry column using R on PowerBi

Tags: r, powerbi, geometry, r-sf

I'm trying to import a gdb file into my PowerBi using R as follows:

```
library(readr, quietly = T)
library(sf, quietly = T)
library(dplyr, quietly = T)
library(tidyr, quietly = T)

boundariesConstituencies <- st_read("C:/Borough_Councils/district_borough_unitary_region/district_borough_unitary_region.gdb", "district_borough_unitary_region") %>% 
  select(constituency = NAME) %>% 
  st_set_crs(27700) %>% 
  st_transform(4326)
```

I am able to read the gdb file and get the first column, but there is an error in the geometry column:

[image]

The error I get: "**DataFormat.Error: We cannot convert this value from its .RData representation.**"

This script works just fine in RStudio.

Any ideas how to import the geometry into powerBI?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use your map in Power BI you have to export it not as .RData, but as a TopoJSON, and import it via a custom map of the Shape map Power BI control; have a look at the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-shape-map - note that this control used to require specifically checking a box for allowing a feature in preview version (the feature is labelled "preview" for as long as I can remember, which is several years)

An approach that I would suggest is to create your output in two steps:

1. create a TopoJSON file of your boundaries, with keys (name may not be a perfect key, but it will do) + use it for the Shape map control
2. import an actual dataset that will link to map polygons via the key declared earlier

For an example of saving a TopoJSON from your data consider this piece of code (as I don't have your actual data I am shooting blind, so no 100% guarantee, but it is not a difficult piece of code and has served me well in the past).

```
boundariesConstituencies %>%
  mutate(id = NAME) %>% # this will be your key for linking data later on!
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>% 
  geojsonio::topojson_json(object_name = "whatever", crs = 4326) %>% 
  jsonlite::write("whatever.json")
```